# Scala value class that supports comparisons and maths operations

Tags: scala

What is an idomatic way to create a value class in Scala that supports supports comparisons and mathematical operations?  Suppose I have the following value class...

```
case class Price(value: Double) extends AnyVal
```

I would like to be able to do things like...

```
val price1 = Price(23.4)
val price2 = Price(1.0)

price1 <= price2
price1 + price2
```

...etc for all other comparison and mathematical operators.  One solution is to implement each of the desired methods by hand...

```
case class Price(value: Double) extends AnyVal {

   def <=(that: Price): Boolean = this.value <= that.value

}
```

...but I think there must be a better way. Thoughts?

Comment: Check out the Spire library (https://github.com/non/spire). It may be overkill, though

Comment: @Eduardo Very cool! But, I would prefer a solution using the standard library.

Comment: what about implicit conversion to underlying?

Comment: @Samar Defined where? In a companion object?  Would this defeat the purpose of using a value class? I think the compiler "converts" value classes to the underlying representation to avoid the overhead of actually creating instances of the value class. Would defining an implicit conversion force the compiler to explicitly create instances of Price?

Comment: You could define the conversion where you are defining the value class. And then import it wherever you need it. I don't think an implicit conversion to `Double` is causing an instantiation of the value class in this case. You can check javap output to verify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the standard Scala library you will want to implement the `Ordering`, `Numeric`, or `Fractional` type class for `Price`. These are refinements, where `Ordering[A] <: Numeric [A] <: Fractional[A]`. For the comparisons, like `<=`, you just need `Ordering`, for addition, multiplication, subtraction etc. you need `Numeric`, and `Fractional` would add division.

Unfortunately, there is no "shortcut" to using the `Double` functionality, so you need to at least write forwarders for all relevant methods:

```scala
object PriceIsFractional extends Fractional[Price] {
  // Ordering:
  def compare(x: Price,y: Price): Int = x.value compare y.value

  // Numeric:      
  def plus (x: Price,y: Price): Price = Price(x.value + y.value)
  def minus(x: Price,y: Price): Price = Price(x.value - y.value)
  def times(x: Price,y: Price): Price = Price(x.value * y.value)
  def negate(x: Price): Price = Price(-x.value)
  def fromInt (x: Int): Price = Price(x.toDouble)
  def toInt   (x: Price): Int    = x.value.toInt
  def toLong  (x: Price): Long   = x.value.toLong
  def toFloat (x: Price): Float  = x.value.toFloat
  def toDouble(x: Price): Double = x.value

  // Fractional:
  def div(x: Price,y: Price): Price = Price(x.value / y.value)
}

// The following enables comparison operators:
import PriceIsFractional.mkOrderingOps

price1 <= price2   // works now

// The following enables numeric operators:
import PriceIsFractional.mkNumericOps

price1 + price2    // works now
```

Comment: But here Price does not extend AnyVal?

Comment: I don't define `Price`, it's exactly as defined in the question by the OP. I simply define a type class for numeric operations.

Comment: @0__ is it possible to define these operations on the companion object for Price is such a way that they are always available without having to manually import?

Comment: @davidrpugh No, only type classes are found automatically in standard places, extension methods must always have an import. However you can just put forwarders in the companion object. Like `object Price { implicit def mkOrderingOps = ...; implicit def mkNumericOps = ... }`

Comment: @0__ I am having trouble getting the implicit forwarders in the companion object to work.  Can you give me some more explicit details? If so, then I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following the solution above and off the top of my head, it should be easy to auto-generate the things you need. You can alternatively use implicit macros instead, which are typed and don't require macro paradise, but for the sake of argument, this is a trivial way to skip the boilerplate.

We are generating an implicit instance of the `Functional[MyType]` typeclass inside the companion object of `MyType`, or in your case we are generating the companion object `object Price { implicit object bla extends Fractional[Price] { .. } }`

We do this because in this way Scala can automatically look for implicits inside the companion object so we don't require explicit imports.

```
    @macrocompat.bundle
    class FractionalMacro(val c: scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context) {

      import c.universe._

      /**
        * Retrieves the accessor fields on a case class and returns an iterable of tuples of the form Name -> Type.
        * For every single field in a case class, a reference to the string name and string type of the field are returned.
        *
        * Example:
        *
        * {{{
        *   case class Test(id: UUID, name: String, age: Int)
        *
        *   accessors(Test) = Iterable("id" -> "UUID", "name" -> "String", age: "Int")
        * }}}
        *
        * @param params The list of params retrieved from the case class.
        * @return An iterable of tuples where each tuple encodes the string name and string type of a field.
        */
      def accessors(
        params: Seq[c.universe.ValDef]
      ): Iterable[(c.universe.TermName, c.universe.TypeName)] = {
        params.map {
          case ValDef(_, name: TermName, tpt: Tree, _) => name -> TypeName(tpt.toString)
        }
      }

      def makeFunctional(
        tpe: c.TypeName,
        name: c.TermName,
        params: Seq[ValDef]
      ): Tree = {

        val fresh = c.freshName(name)
        val applies = accessors(params).headOption match {
          case Some(field) => field._1
          case None => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Expected one arg")
        }

        q"""implicit object $fresh extends scala.math.Fractional[$tpe] {
// Ordering:
  def compare(x: $tpe, y: $tpe): Int = x.$field compare y.$field

  // Numeric:      
  def plus(x: $tpe,y: $tpe): $tpe = $name(x.$field + y.$field)
  def minus(x: $tpe,y: $tpe): $tpe = $name(x.$field - y.$field)
  def times(x: $tpe, y: $tpe): $tpe = $name(x.$field * y.$field)
  def negate(x: $tpe): $tpe = $name(-x.$field)
  def fromInt (x: Int): $tpe = $name(x.$field.toDouble)
  def toInt   (x: $tpe): Int    = x.$field.toInt
  def toLong  (x: $tpe): Long   = x.$field.toLong
  def toFloat (x: $tpe): Float  = x.$field.toFloat
  def toDouble(x: $tpe): Double = x.$field

  // Fractional:
  def div(x: $tpe, y: $tpe): $tpe = $name(x.value / y.value)
}
        }"""
      }
  def macroImpl(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): Tree =
annottees.map(_.tree) match {
  case (classDef @ q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$params) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }")
    :: Nil if mods.hasFlag(Flag.CASE) =>
    val name = tpname.toTermName

    val res = q"""
   $classDef
   object $name {
     ..${makeFunctional(tpname.toTypeName, name, params.head)}
   }
   """
    println(showCode(res))
    res

  case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Invalid annotation target, Sample must be a case classes")
```

}
        }

In addition you could type check the field to make sure it's of a known mathematical type, or use implicit `Numeric` where applicable so you can delegate to an in scope implicit if need be.

Now pretty much all you need is:

```
@compileTimeOnly("Enable macro paradise to expand macro annotations")
  class fractional extends StaticAnnotation {
    def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro FractionalMacro.macroImpl
  }

@fractional case class Price(value: Double)
```

Implicit macros are a possibility, if you could edit the contents of `Fractional` to add the reference to the implicit macro materialiser to its companion object, but since in this case we cannot edit the default library, this is a cooler way to not have to rely on explicit imports of necessary implicits.

Bonus, this could probably be expanded to deal with more fields, and more complex things.